# Why are those NavigationLinks not clickable?

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
ScrollView () {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
         ForEach(0..<10) {position in
             NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(position)) {
                 TimetableCellView(position)
             }.padding(.all, 0.0)
         }.padding(.all, 0.0)  
    }.cornerRadius(30.0).padding(.all)
}
```

It looks and feels as it should (besides the greyed out look of the TimetableCellViews in the list), but I can't click on the links. Any ideas how to solve?
Thx.

Comment: Most probably you don't have `NavigationView` as a root, because `NavigationLink` works only *inside* `NavigationView`, so just put your `ScrollView` into `NavigationView`.

Comment: Ah thx, this works on devices with the horizontalSizeClass .compact. Else not.

Comment: Any idaes what I could do?